LD_LIBRARY_PATH ignored for Qt6 application
I'm trying to deploy a Qt6 application on a Ubuntu 24.04 machine.
Here my dist content:
.
├── libQt6Core.so
├── libQt6Core.so.6
├── libQt6Core.so.6.8.0
├── libQt6Gui.so
├── libQt6Gui.so.6
├── libQt6Gui.so.6.8.0
├── libQt6SerialPort.so
├── libQt6SerialPort.so.6
├── libQt6SerialPort.so.6.8.0
├── libQt6Widgets.so
├── libQt6Widgets.so.6
├── libQt6Widgets.so.6.8.0
├── MyApp
└── platforms
    └── libqxcb.so

Then I tried to run MyApp as follow:
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) 
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/user/Documents/dist
$ ./MyApp

but it returns:

./MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: libQt6Widgets.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

As you can see the file exists and is there.
After exporting theLD_LIBRARY_PATH this is the output of ldd:
$ ldd MyApp
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc29796000)
    libQt6Widgets.so.6 => not found
    libQt6Gui.so.6 => not found
    libQt6SerialPort.so.6 => not found
    libQt6Core.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007583d5000000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007583d53ff000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007583d4c00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007583d5316000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007583d545a000)

I read this and this questions (among many others) but I still have issues.
Why it does not find the files even if they are there?

First, why are you putting them in your local directory? Why not just add a file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf with contents /home/user/Documents/dist, then run ldconfig? No need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

@BobGoddard, perhaps I didn't understand your hint. But as far as I know, ldconfig will just look in the given path. But I need the libraries in the local directory in order to deploy it to another machine

Sounds like relative 'rpath' embedded in the binary might be a better way to do it?

Also, just to make sure..  is the MyApp executable setuid/setgid or normal?

@grawity, yes, nothing different than normal I think. I'm aware rpath is another way, but I want to learn how to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH in this question.

Can you try LD_DEBUG=libs in addition?
